# Show '>' and '<' symbol in ng-select

Tags: angular

1. Tags being used are `ng-select` and `ng-options`
2. When i give `Location > 100` text, it displays as `Location &gt; 100`
   instead of `Location > 100`. How could I solve it?

```html
<ng-select class="width-100" [(ngModel)]="selectedValues">
  <ng-option *ngFor="let item of singleDropdownData.values" [value]="item">
    {{item}}
  </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code where you are stringifying `Location > 100`

Comment: It would be array of strings. Like for example
updateKmReasons = [
    'Distance mismatch - Bad Location > 100km',
    'Travelled in Alternate Route ',
    'Travelled in Actual Route - Mismatch',
    'Others'
  ];

Comment: So i would be looping through this array in ng-select

Comment: I understand they are strings, but how are you stringifying them in your html, please post the code so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: <ng-select class="width-100" [(ngModel)]="selectedValues">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let item of singleDropdownData.values" [value]="item" >{{item}}</ng-option>
</ng-select> @pavankumar

Comment: It's generally worth checking the 'ol googly machine for a quick reference to the projects [issues and workarounds](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/506) where you can find a fix by just setting the item template as `ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item"`

Comment: check this Stackblitz for an example of ng-select use: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use binding instead of providing the `ng-option`. Bind the values to [items].

```html
<ng-select class="width-100" [items]="singleDropdownData.values" [(ngModel)]="selectedValues">


</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

You have the `updateKmreasons` defined in component:

```
 updateKmReasons = [ 'Distance mismatch - Bad Location > 100km', 'Travelled in Alternate Route ', 'Travelled in Actual Route - Mismatch', 'Others' ];
```

In HTML:

```
<ng-select class="width-100" [(ngModel)]="selectedValues">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let km of updateKmReasons" [value]="km" >{{km}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

here is a [stackblitz-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eg6cft?file=src/data-source-options-example.component.html) for the same:

Comment: <ng-select class="width-100" (change)="chosenOptions()" 
   [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" placeholder=" . 
  {{singleDropdownData.placeholder}}">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let item of singleDropdownData.values" [value]="item" 
         placeholder="this is a test">{{item}}
  </ng-option>
</ng-select>

@nircraft its the same thing I tried. didn't work out.